# US taxes if worked 3 months in US

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I have stayed in the US (NY) from Feb 25 2016 to April 1 2017.

- I have fully paid the taxes for 2016 and filed the paperwork.
- For 2017, the taxes have been deducted from my salary. I need to file the paperwork (asked for an extension)

My question is, how my taxes are going to be calculated for 2017?

PS: I am neither US citizen nor Green Card holder.

Comment: What status are you in?

Comment: I am living in EU now and do not have any relationships with US.

Comment: I meant to ask, which status you _were_ in the US when you received your US income? This affects whether you were a resident or a non-resident alien. Some statuses are exempt from tax residency. Also, if you were a dual-status alien in 2016 and you're married and your spouse was with you, you can choose to be treated as a resident alien for the entire 2016, which would reduce your tax liability. The year you left, you're probably a dual status resident, but again this depends on which status you were in.

Comment: I was on L-1 visa